# 500 Internal Server Error after I deployed my springboot application

Tags: java, spring-boot, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I deployed my java web application to AWS Elastic Beanstalk and when I try to go to my admin page(by clicking a tab and redirect to admin page), I always get 500 error. But other pages works fine. Any one know how to solve this issue?
Error log shown below:

```
/var/log/nginx/error.log
----------------------------------------
2020/09/01 02:52:52 [error] 4414#0: *1 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 172.31.10.245, server: , request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:5000/", host: "172.31.27.65"
2020/09/01 02:52:57 [error] 4414#0: *3 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 172.31.21.57, server: , request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:5000/", host: "172.31.27.65"
2020/09/01 03:27:08 [error] 31583#0: *1 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 172.31.10.245, server: , request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:5000/", host: "172.31.27.65"
2020/09/01 03:27:14 [error] 31583#0: *3 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 172.31.21.57, server: , request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:5000/", host: "172.31.27.65"
```

Comment: Have you set EB env variable `SERVER_PORT` to `5000`?

Comment: Yes. Only this function has 500 error.